# Enable the pink alignment lines after they disappeared

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I've been using Photoshop CS5 for some time now and realized that I disabled align lines somehow and want them back.

For example, when I have a circle and I'm moving another one around it Photoshop should display pink alignment lines and "dock" the second circle to the first one.

How do I fix that and get them showing again?

Answer (score 7):

These lines are probably smart guides.

To toggle them on/off, go to:

> View > Show > Smart Guides